# How to achieve 3D plot this in python or SageMath with contours?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, sage

I want to plot a quadratic form with its level sets in SageMath. How to do that?

I want the following diagram.
[image]
The following is my try.

But it did not give me the same figure as in the above pic.

The output was separate files.
[First one]
[image]
and the second one is the [contour plot][image], rest all same

```
plot = Graphics()
plot+=plot3d(1/4*x^2+1/9*y^2,(x,-2,2),(y,-2,2))
for h in [0..5]:
    plot+=contour_plot(f,(x,-4,4),(y,-4,4), fill=false, labels=true, contours=10,colorbar=true,cmap=matplotlib.cm.gist_rainbow).show(aspect_ratio=1)    
show(plot)
```

### How to achieve this?

Suggestions in plain python using `matplotlib` is also fine.

Comment: I like this, but I am not sure one can convert contour plots to 3d in Sage yet.  `NotImplementedError: 3D plotting not implemented for ContourPlot`  In matplotlib I wouldn't be surprised if this is supported, though; I haven't used their 3d plotting much.